# Show that the series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{(n+1)^3}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that the series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{(n+1)^3}$ converges. Which convergence test would be suitable to prove this though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may observe that, for $n=1,2,\cdots,$
$$
0<\frac{2n}{(n+1)^3}\le \frac{2n}{n^3}=\frac{2}{n^2}
$$ then one may use the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).

Answer (score 3):

One has: $$\frac{2n}{(n+1)^3}\sim\frac{2}{n^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Or one has 
$$
\frac{2n}{(n+1)^3}=\frac{2}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{2}{(n+1)^3}.
$$